# retrieve percentile rank using php with joomla 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, rank, percentile

I have been trying to obtain the percentile rank of user based on score.  I can get the result in phpmyadmin - but can't seem to get the code right in php.......

here is what i have so far....

```
$db=JFactory::getDBO();
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$userId = $user->id;

$rank = "SELECT rank, cb_cscore,(SELECT 100*(rank / count(*)) FROM  `e72jm_comprofiler`,(SELECT @rownum :=0)r WHERE cb_cscore IS NOT NULL) as percentage FROM (SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, `cb_cscore` , `user_id` FROM `e72jm_comprofiler`,(SELECT @row :=0) r WHERE cb_cscore IS NOT NULL AND user_id = $userId LIMIT 0,1";

$db->setQuery( $rank );
$db->query();
```

but - i keep getting stuck on how to load the results...

meaning how to load the result from the query.....

any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

```
$rank = "SELECT rank, cb_cscore,(SELECT 100*(rank / count(*)) as percentile FROM  `e72jm_comprofiler`,(SELECT @rownum :=0)r WHERE cb_cscore IS NOT NULL) as percentage FROM (SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, `cb_cscore` , `user_id` FROM `e72jm_comprofiler`,(SELECT @row :=0) r WHERE cb_cscore IS NOT NULL AND user_id = $userId LIMIT 0,1";
```

Then just access it as a "percentile" column like you would any other.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're not defining the database table correctly in your query. You need to use the prefix `#__`, so in your case, it wold be `#__comprofiler` instead of `e72jm_comprofiler`

Secondly, you don't need to use the `&` operator, so change `=& JFactory` to `= JFactory`

Thirdly, remove `$db->query();` as it is used when inserting data into the database or updating it

Then you then need to define the results using `$rows = $db->loadObjectList();`

And finally you can display the results using a `foreach` loop seeing as it will be an array.

***Final code:***

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$userId = $user->id;

$rank = "SELECT rank, cb_cscore,(SELECT 100*(rank / count(*)) FROM  `#__comprofiler`,(SELECT @rownum :=0)r WHERE cb_cscore IS NOT NULL) as percentage FROM (SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, `cb_cscore` , `user_id` FROM `#__comprofiler`,(SELECT @row :=0) r WHERE cb_cscore IS NOT NULL AND user_id = $userId LIMIT 0,1";

$db->setQuery($rank);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($rows as $row) {              
  echo $row->rank;
  echo $row->cb_cscore;
}
```

May I also suggest you take a look at using Joomla 2.5 coding standards for your database query:

http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$db=JFactory::getDBO();
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$userId = $user->id;

    $rank = "SELECT rank, cb_cscore,
    (SELECT 100*(rank / count(*)) FROM  `e72jm_comprofiler`,
    (SELECT @rownum :=0)r WHERE cb_cscore IS NOT NULL) as percentage 
FROM (SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, `cb_cscore` , `user_id` FROM `e72jm_comprofiler`,

    (SELECT @row :=0) r WHERE cb_cscore IS NOT NULL) 
    AND user_id = $userId LIMIT 0,1";

$db->setQuery( $rank );
$db->query();
$res = $db->loadAssocList();//if the result is single row you can use $db->loadAssoc();
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($res);
```

Comment: i tried both loadAssocList and LoadAssoc but still couldn't get it to load.  suggestions on maybe just a simple way to grab the user rank and then wait to calculate the percentage separately?

Comment: just echo  the query and paste it to phpmyadmin and check for any error in the query pls letme know the status

Comment: In the phpmyadmin - this works the best       SET @rownum := 0; 
SELECT rank, cb_cscore,(SELECT 100*(rank / count(*)) FROM  `e72jm_comprofiler`
WHERE cb_cscore > 0) as percentage
FROM (
SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, `cb_cscore` , `user_id`
FROM `e72jm_comprofiler`
WHERE cb_cscore > 0
ORDER BY `cb_cscore` DESC 
) AS result
WHERE `user_id` =42
LIMIT 1

Comment: but couldn't figure out the first select in the php side

Comment: while checking your query in detail found one ) is missing pls check that too

Comment: longer way but seems to work
$totalusers = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM `#_comprofiler` WHERE `cb_cscore` IS NOT NULL";
$db->setQuery( $totalusers );
$total = $db->loadResult();
echo $total."total<br/>";


$placement = "SELECT COUNT(*) as userrank FROM `#_comprofiler` WHERE `cb_cscore` IS NOT NULL AND cb_cscore > (SELECT cb_cscore FROM `#_comprofiler` WHERE user_id = $userId )";
$db->setQuery( $placement );
$userrank = $db->loadResult();
echo $userrank."user<br/>";



$ranking = $userrank/$total;
echo "<br/>ranking".$ranking;

$percentile = round($ranking * 100,0);
echo "<br/>".$percentile;